# Predefine a specific twitter feed to display

Tags: objective-c, twitter, ios7.1, acaccount

In the code below, a tableview displays the twitter feed of the user of the phone. All I want to do is display the feed of a user that I predefine in the code. I looked online but can't find any tutorials on this. I would like to edit this code instead of restarting with a third party API.

ViewController.m

```
#import "TwitterViewController.h"
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface TwitterViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *twitterArray;

@end

@implementation TwitterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self twitterTimeline];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)twitterTimeline {

    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]; // Creates AccountStore object.

    // Asks for the Twitter accounts configured on the device.

    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         // If we have access to the Twitter accounts configured on the device we will contact the Twitter API.

         if (granted == YES){


             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType]; // Retrieves an array of Twitter accounts configured on the device.

             // If there is a leat one account we will contact the Twitter API.

             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) {

                 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject]; // Sets the last account on the device to the twitterAccount variable.

                 NSURL *requestAPI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"]; // API call that returns entires in a user's timeline.

                 // The requestAPI requires us to tell it how much data to return so we use a NSDictionary to set the 'count'.

                 NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                 [parameters setObject:@"100" forKey:@"count"];

                 [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

                 // This is where we are getting the data using SLRequest.

                 SLRequest *posts = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestAPI parameters:parameters];

                 posts.account = twitterAccount;

                 // The postRequest: method call now accesses the NSData object returned.

                 [posts performRequestWithHandler:

                  ^(NSData *response, NSHTTPURLResponse
                    *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      // The NSJSONSerialization class is then used to parse the data returned and assign it to our array.

                      self.twitterArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                      if (self.twitterArray.count != 0) {

                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                              [self.twitterFeedTable reloadData]; // Here we tell the table view to reload the data it just recieved.

                          });

                      }

                  }];

             }

         } else {

             // Handle failure to get account access
             NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

         }

     }];

}

#pragma mark Table View Data Source Mehtods

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Returns the number of rows for the table view using the array instance variable.

    return [_twitterArray count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Creates each cell for the table view.

    static NSString *cellID =  @"CELLID" ;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.twitterFeedTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];

    }

    // Creates an NSDictionary that holds the user's posts and then loads the data into each cell of the table view.

    NSDictionary *tweet = _twitterArray[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = tweet[@"text"];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // When a user selects a row this will deselect the row.

    [self.twitterFeedTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is [here in the docs.](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

You need to add either a `user_id` parameter or a `screen_name` parameter to your `http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json` request, and that's all.

Example as provided in the documentation:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi
```